# How to append tensor value to tensor array?

Tags: python, tensorflow

We try to convert a randomly assigned tensor from 0 to 255 into a histogram and apply a smoothing filter to the histogram.
I am trying to add the result of the filter operation to a new array tensor, but I get an error about shape. Please solve it.
tensorflow version 2.0.0

```
x = tf.random.uniform(shape=[32,32], minval=0, maxval=255, dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.reshape(x, [1024])
print("x",x)
#H = get2dHistogram(x, y, value_range=[[0.0,1.0], [0.0,1.0]], nbins=100, dtype=tf.dtypes.int32)
H = tf.histogram_fixed_width(x, value_range=[0, 255], nbins=256)
H = tf.cast(H, tf.float32)
print(H)
print("shape: ",np.shape(H))
filter_size = 7
zero_n = int(filter_size/2)
zeros = tf.constant([0.0]*zero_n)
print(zeros)

new = tf.concat([zeros, H], 0)
print(new)
print("shape: ",np.shape(new))
new = tf.concat([new, zeros], 0)
print(new)
print("shape: ",np.shape(new))

filter_size = 7
filter_list = []
for i in range(filter_size): # make filter array
    filter_list.append(float(1/filter_size))
filter_array = np.array(filter_list, dtype = np.float32)
filter_array_tf = tf.constant(filter_array, dtype=tf.float32)
print("filter_array_tf:", filter_array_tf)

sm_hist = []
sm_hist = np.array(sm_hist, dtype=np.float32)
sm_hist_tf = tf.constant(sm_hist, dtype=tf.float32)

for i in range(0, 256):
    alist = new[i:i+filter_size]
    alist = tf.multiply(alist, filter_array_tf)
    alist = tf.reduce_sum(alist)
    print("alist:", alist)
    print("sm_hist_tf:", sm_hist_tf)
    sm_hist_tf = tf.concat([sm_hist_tf, alist], 0)

print(sm_hist_tf)
```

The error that I get:

```
InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Ranks of all input tensors should match: shape[0] = [0] vs. shape[1] = [] [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the last line of your for loop to:

```
sm_hist_tf = tf.concat([sm_hist_tf, tf.expand_dims(alist,0)], 0)
```